# Does anyone know the name of this goddess?

Tags: goddess, identification-request

The following image is of an unknown [goddess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqfoM.jpg). Does anyone know the name of this goddess?

[image: Unknown goddess]

Sitting on the shoulder of Vetala with a sickle in right hand and a severed head in left hand.

Comment: From where did you get this photo? Any blogs or somewhere?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ZhRCs4aHgd4?t=7s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It's [Goddess Chamunda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamunda).

Unlike what others have said, the person carrying her is not a vetala, it's a preta.

From the Iconography

> The black or red coloured Chamunda is described as wearing a **garland of severed heads or skulls (Mundamala)**. She is described as having four, eight, ten or **twelve arms**, holding a Damaru (drum), trishula (trident), sword, a snake, skull-mace (khatvanga), thunderbolt, a **severed head** and **panapatra** (drinking vessel, wine cup) or skull-cup (kapala), filled with blood. **Standing on a corpse** of a man (shava or preta) or seated on a defeated demon or corpse (pretasana). ... Sometimes, a **crescent moon is seen on her head**.[4][5] Her socket eyes are described as so intense that it burns the evil of all three worlds. She is **accompanied by fiends and goblins**.[5][6] She is also shown to be surrounded by skeletons or ghosts and beasts like jackals, who are shown eating the flesh of the corpse which the goddess sits or stands on.

(I have emphasized the characteristics matching with the image which you have shared)

This is another image of hers, from the Wikipedia page:

[image]

In the Durga Saptashati, it's clearly mentioned that she rides a preta.

> ***chamunda devi rides preta***, barahi rides on buffallo,
> aindri uses elephant, vaishnavi rides garuda.
> maheshwari rides on ox, kaumari rides on peacock.
> consort of lord Vishnu, lakshamidevi sits on lotus with
> lotus in her hands.

---

She is one of the [**Ashta Matrikas**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrikas#Iconography)

From there:

> The black coloured Chamunda is described as wearing a **garland of severed heads or skulls (Mundamala)** and holding a Damaru (drum), trishula (trident), sword and **pānapātra** (drinking-vessel). Riding a jackal or standing on a corpse of a man (shava or preta), **she is described as having three eyes, a terrifying face and a sunken belly**.

Comment: She is Bhadrakali & not Chamunda !

Answer (score 2):

**Bhagvathy Bhadrakali**

She is Bhadrakali as per Kerala Agams. It wouldn't be wrong to say that Kerala is land of Bhadrakali and Nagas. As these two deities are revered so highly in every house.

There is a folk song describing war of Bhadrakali and Darukasura, in Malayalam. That can justify this iconography,

> **Vedala vahanameri**
> Pogunnu thampuratti
> Dariga pura sannidhi thannil
> Chennadkkunnu anganangane

Actually, if you see the folk song describe her riding a Vedala or Vetala or a Betala.

(Ps- Idk Malayalam, yet this song is a whole different vibe,[this](https://youtu.be/4SDRrctDkvk) is the rock version of the folk song, & [here](https://youtu.be/Oz1VIDcK1Mk) it is, this is the original traditional version. Actually Vidya Vox in her 'let me be free' sung the same song in mashup.)

Here are some more beautiful images of Bhagwathy riding Betala.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This, particular image is of **Shree Attukal Bhagvathy Bhadrakali, Thiruvananthapuram**

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Answer (score 1):

This image closely resembles Goddess Kaalaraatri. She is mentioned in famous texts like Sri Durga Saptashati. But she is on VetAla which is not a common vehicle for goddesses.

Kaalratri (sometimes spelled Kalaratri) is the seventh form amongst the Navadurga (ie. the nine forms of Hindu Mother Goddess referenced in Durga Saptashati, Chapters 81-93 of the Markandeya Purana, the earliest known literature on Goddess Durga). Goddess Kaalratri is widely regarded as one of the many destructive forms of Mother Goddess - Kali, Mahakali, Bhadrakali, Bhairavi, Mrityu, Rudrani, Chamunda, Chandi and Durga.
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaalratri)

Another possibility is Goddess Sri Dhoomavati which is one of 10 mahAvidyAs. She is also very famous among the shakta tradition. 
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhumavati)

Comment: Neither of them sit on an old woman, which is the most distinctive feature of this image.  Because there's a whole bunch of Shakti-related goddesses that have the other attributes.

Comment: its not woman but vetala

Comment: I know about Goddess Kaalratri ( one of Nav Durga ) but she seats on donkey and Dhoomvati seat on chariot or crow but why she seated on the shoulder of old women?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi OK, but whether human or Vetala, it is female, right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vetala

Comment: could be vetala cause it looks like one from Baital Pachisi story

Answer (score 1):

The weapon she holds and the ornament in her legs indicate that she might belong to the Southern part of India (Dravidian). Maybe Tamilnadu or Andhra And the people on the background looks like asuras, the heads in her hands looks human' she also stores the blood with a cup like thing like the god Muni, and the woman that is lifting her doesn't look human friendly and she has more than eight arms so, I'm guessing that she might be a Goddess to the Asuras.(I may be wrong. It's just my assumption. She might be a Goddess to the humans too). you can find idols like this in South Indian Temples They are old Gods still worshipped today [image]

[image]

Comment: Not even close.